# Only allow specific components types as children

Tags: angular

I want to create a navbar and would like to allow only navitems as children like so:

```
<app-navbar>
  <app-navitem label="label1"></app-navitem>
  <app-navitem label="label2"></app-navitem>
  <app-navitem label="label3"></app-navitem>
</app-navbar>
```

But would like to prevent someone from doing this

```
<app-navbar>
  <p>label1</p>
  <div>some other html</div>
</app-navbar>
```

Is this possible in angular?

PS: I've seen some react example but couldn't find angular ones so quite possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do so would be to pass a list of labels to the `<app-navbar>` and to let it loop over them to include `<app-navitem>` items internally :

```html
<app-navbar [labels]="labels"></app-navbar>
```

NavBarComponent template :

```html
  <app-navitem *ngFor="let label of labels" [label]="label"></app-navitem>
```

This way, you can't inject additional html content into your NavBarComponent template.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-content with select name.

```
<app-navbar>
      <app-navitem child-item label="label1"></app-navitem>
      <app-navitem child-item label="label2"></app-navitem>
      <app-navitem child-item label="label3"></app-navitem>
      <p>label1</p>
      <div>some other html</div>
 </app-navbar>
```

And in app-navbar html, you could use:

```
<ng-content select="[child-item]"></ng-content>
```

This will ensure that only items with child-item attribute will be accepted.

**Note:** This won't work if another child element uses that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, this is the typescript code implementation :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({...})
    export class NavItemComponent {
    
      @Input()
      label: string;
    
     }
```